# Does Dart compiler enforces privacy for any identifier prefixed with an underscore?

Tags: dart

According to Dart docs: The Dart compiler enforces privacy for any identifier prefixed with an underscore

Which implies... The following code should fail at `bike._speed = 8;`, but it doesn't. Am I reading the docs wrong?

```
class Bicycle {
  int cadence;
  int _speed;
  int gear;

  Bicycle(this.cadence, this.gear);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Bicycle: $_speed mph, cadence: $cadence';
}

void main() {
  final bike = Bicycle(2, 1);
  bike.cadence = 9;
  bike._speed = 8;
  print(bike);
  print(bike.cadence);
  print(bike._speed);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit of [privacy](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility) is a `library` not just a class.

> Libraries not only provide APIs, but are a unit of privacy:
>   identifiers that start with an underscore (_) are visible only inside
>   the library. Every Dart app is a library, even if it doesn’t use a
>   library directive.

This means that two classes in the same library have access to each other's underscore fields and methods.

The second sentence is why your `main` can access `_speed`. Your app constitutes a stand-alone library, so `main` has full access to `Bicycle` (but not any classes that are imported from other libraries).

Comment: You might want to add a brief explanation about what a "library" is in Dart (typically separate files).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Richard